# AJAX request waits for another request to finish

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to display installation progress with AJAX.
my PHP code looks like this:

```
if($method == "install"){
  $_SESSION['progress']="step 1";
  $obj->thisTakesAboutAMinute();
  $_SESSION['progress']="step 2";
  $obj->thisTakesAboutAMinute();
  .
  .
  .
}else if($method == "getProgress"){
  echo($_SESSION['progress']);
}
```

when page loads i set interval for "getProgress" function

```
setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "./scripts/script.php",
       async: true,
       data: {method: "getProgress"}
     }).done(function( msg ) {
       $("#message").html(msg);
     });
   }, 1000);
```

and "install" is called after pressing button.

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "./scripts/script.php",
     async: true,
     data: {method: "install"}
 });
```

Problem is that when i fire "install" request "getProgress" requests stop returning until "install" finishes and then return all at once.
https://postimg.org/image/hj72qdnhr/

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get the exact progress, because there is a lot of uncertainties, the script execution time, networking delay and browser processing time, etc., all of these are volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Place code inside `success` function.Because done function always executes after completion of ajax call.So you feel like waiting due to second ajax call..so

```
setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "./scripts/script.php",
       async: true,
       data: {method: "getProgress"},
       success:function(msg){
       $("#message").html(msg);
         }
     });
   }, 1000);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answer! i tried substituting done with success before, unfortunately problem still persists.